# Concat string in $scope angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass string name through argument in function and concat in $scope, this is possible?

```
function test(txt){
 $scope.person. + txt; // I want to do $scope.person.status; for example
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just do:

```
function test(txt){
   $scope.person[txt];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works =]

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(txt){
  $scope.person[txt] = '';  // We need to assign something to it if not it wont work;
 }
```

Demo example :  https://jsbin.com/gihizo/3/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

Check [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

As any object you can access their properties using **Dot notation** or **Bracket notation**. When you don't know before hand what property you would be accessing you would use **Bracket notation** ideally.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read about.